# Dokku Port configuration problems EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, docker, dokku

I currently trying to deploy my App on a EC2 Instance using Dokku and my first impression is that it's really amazing. Still I have some problems relating the configuration of my App that it's reachable via port 80 and not to the docker container port.

So for instance when i try to reach my app it's reachable under:

http://recipeapp.xxx.de:49169/

but not under

http://recipeapp.xxx.de/

My VHOST config looks like this:

```
    xxx.de
```

The nginx.conf of the app is generated as the following:

```
upstream recipeapp { server 127.0.0.1:49169; }
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name recipeapp.xxx.de;
  location    / {
    proxy_pass  http://recipeapp;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
      }
}
```

I add my remote with:
     git remote add appstore dokku@xxx:recipeapp

And push it with:
    git push appstore master

So what am I doing wrong? I now trying it for days to make it running correct but I don't see any possibilities any more.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing when you hit http://recipeapp.xxx.de/? Is it nginx? or does it just hang?

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck the contents of `/home/dokku/VHOST` as root. The file should contain a single line, namely "xxx.de".

If the file is absent, `touch /home/dokku/VHOST` and enter the line.

Also keep in mind that you need to configure the DNS settings for xxx.de; A record for xxx.de pointing to EC2 instance and A record for *.xxx.de also pointing to EC2 instance.

Hope this helps.